# How to make a drive mount avaialble inside a container?

Tags: lxc, containers

I intend to use the mount inside the container for a postgres database.

I have been unable to make the drive available inside the container.
So far I have:

1. mounted `/dev/sdb` to `/mnt/psql` on the host device.
2. created `/mnt/psql` directory in the container.
3. added `lxc.mount.entry = /mnt/psql mnt/psql none bind 0 0` to the lxc container config files.

Upon restarting the container, the mount was still not available.
How do I go about making it available?

Comment: You can use `fstab` to declare mount points using `lxc.mount  = /PATH/TO/fstab`.

Comment: Would the path be to the host's or container's fstab file?

Comment: This is an extension to LXC's `config` file. I usually put them together, outside the container's `rootfs`.

Comment: I've just tried to add `lxc.mount = /PATH/TO/HOSTS/fstab` and `lxc.mount = /PATH/TO/CONTAINERS/fstab`, then restarted the container however the files are still not available in `/mnt/psql`. Am I missing something? The drive is mounted fine in the host.

Comment: The format of this `fstab` is equal to `/etc/fstab`, but the mount point is relative to the container's root. For example: `/mnt/psql                    mnt/psql             none    bind,rw                 0       0`

Comment: Is your container an unprivileged one? If yes, does the user from container has access to `/mnt/psql` ?

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. I removed the `lxc.mount.entry` line from the container config file, then inserted `/mnt/psql mnt/psql none bind,rw 0 0` inside the containers fstab file 'var/lib/lxc/postgres/fstab'. Upon restart the files are available :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fstab` to declare mount points using:

```
lxc.mount = /PATH/TO/fstab
```

This is an extension to LXC's `config` file. I usually put them together, outside the container's `rootfs`. Then, inside that `fstab`, you put entries like the normal `/etc/fstab` but the mount point is relative to the container's `rootfs`. For example:

```
/mnt/psql mnt/psql none bind,rw 0 0
```

See you!